# Filtering Dataframe Columns by unique column combinations even when flipped python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Row Col1  Col2
1   907   952
2   904   895
3   895   904
4   538   454
5   454   538
6   184   472
7   472   184
8   763   792
```

I want to filter the unique row combinations here. For example, row 2 and row 3 are the same because they have the same values, only flipped in one row. Same for rows 4 and 5, and also rows 6 and 7. The final output I want is this:

```
Row Col1  Col2
1   907   952
2   904   895
4   538   454
6   184   472
8   763   792
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
df.groupby(df[['Col1', 'Col2']].apply(sorted, axis=1).astype(str)).head(1)
```

Output:

```
   Row  Col1  Col2
0    1   907   952
1    2   904   895
3    4   538   454
5    6   184   472
7    8   763   792
```

Faster method: `df.groupby([str(sorted(x)) for x in zip(df['Col1'], df['Col2'])]).head(1)`

Comment: IMO, `tuple(sorted(x))` is better than `str(sorted(x))`

Comment: @QuangHoang that didn't work for me in that second syntax.